# Bitbucket not accepting EC2 ssh-key

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, ssh, bitbucket

I've tried to import id_rsa.pub that I generate from my EC2 terminal to my bitbucket account so I don't need to input auth password over and over again when I doing git command. But it seems the Bitbucket still rejected it.

[image: Could not read from repository]

Also please suggest me the simplest webhook that I could create to pull the repository via php exec command so I can doing pull request with link on web browser.

Thanks,

Comment: What have you tried? Doesthis file exist: `~/.ssh/id_rsa`? Is it a properly formatted instance of a private-key added to bitbucket? Have you configured git CLI to use ssh?

Comment: I generated the file of id_rsa by using ssh-keygen command its of course generated two new files (public and private key). I've added the contents of the .pub file to bitbucket but it's not worked in my EC2 instance. By the way, this things only happened in EC2 amazon, when I tried it with other computer, it's worked well. Do you know why?

Comment: First, check the results of `ssh -v dedenbangkit@bitbucket.org`, if your key is listed, then the key you generated on that EC2 instance may be with a different algorithm or encoding than BitBucket will handle. Try generating a new set of keys on the machine where it  _worked_, then add the private key to the EC2, the pub to BitBucket, then check `ssh -v dedenbangkit@bitbucket.org` again.

Comment: @TonyChiboucas I was created the ssh-key without sudoers so it's the file owner problem, I thought sudo can own all the things that created by other groups or users. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Check your ssh user and key

`ssh -v user@domain.com`

This should list the private key your registered with BitBucket. If it does *NOT*, then a little extra configuration may get you there:

#### `~/.ssh/config`

```
host domain.com
user username
identityfile ~/.ssh/id_rsa # path to your private-key-file
```

## Generate the key on another computer.

OS versions and configurations can use any number of encryption algorithms and encoding methods for creating and storing the key-pair. Sometimes these methods don't transfer well between OSs, or won't play nice in different environments.

1. Check your SSH protocol and client. You may need a different or newer version.
2. If all else fails, generate the key on a computer that you *know* works for keygen, then figure out how to get this key working.

Comment: Wow, it works well now! thanks very much. By the way do you think it's safe to run exec with sudo on the webhook?

Comment: No sudo exec git hooks. I'm not aware of any known vulnerabilities here, but you're asking for trouble if you're ever calling exec with super privledges on generated code. The test is this: is there _any_ piece of what will be sent to `exec` which could come from a file that could be written to by any user other than root? If yes, don't do it.